# Convert C CRC16 to Java CRC16

Tags: java, c, crc

I am currently working on a project, having an embedded system sending data to a PC via radio. The packets get a crc16 checksum at the end and it's calculated based on this algorithm:

```
uint16_t crc16 (const uint8_t * buffer, uint32_t size) {
    uint16_t crc = 0xFFFF;

    if (buffer && size)
        while (size--)
        {
            crc = (crc >> 8) | (crc << 8);
            crc ^= *buffer++;
            crc ^= ((unsigned char) crc) >> 4;
            crc ^= crc << 12;
            crc ^= (crc & 0xFF) << 5;
        }

    return crc;
}
```

Now I am looking for an equivalent in Java. I already found a good one here:
http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/51data/CRC16CCITT.java.html

```
public class CRC16CCITT { 

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int crc = 0xFFFF;          // initial value
        int polynomial = 0x1021;   // 0001 0000 0010 0001  (0, 5, 12) 

        // byte[] testBytes = "123456789".getBytes("ASCII");

        byte[] bytes = args[0].getBytes();

        for (byte b : bytes) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                boolean bit = ((b   >> (7-i) & 1) == 1);
                boolean c15 = ((crc >> 15    & 1) == 1);
                crc <<= 1;
                if (c15 ^ bit) crc ^= polynomial;
             }
        }

        crc &= 0xffff;
        System.out.println("CRC16-CCITT = " + Integer.toHexString(crc));
    }

}
```

But this doesnt work with my C Code.

Is anybody able to deliver an adaption or solution for a C and Java equivalent algorithm?
Thank you!

Comment: Why are you setting `crc = ` on every iteration as this is the same as ignoring every value but the last.

Comment: So what do I have to write then? crc ^= ? I just copied the code from an open source project i ones worked with.

Comment: There are much faster ways to compute CRcs than this. Keep searching. There is a table-driven method.

Comment: The link in the OP is dead, here is an updated link: [http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/61data/CRC16CCITT.java.html](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/61data/CRC16CCITT.java.html)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The major difference between java and c in this case is the fact in c you use unsigned numbers and java has only signed numbers. While you can implement the same algorithm with signed numbers, you have to be aware of the fact the sign bit is carried over on shift operations, requiring an extra "and".

This is my implementation:

```
static int crc16(final byte[] buffer) {
    int crc = 0xFFFF;

    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length ; j++) {
        crc = ((crc  >>> 8) | (crc  << 8) )& 0xffff;
        crc ^= (buffer[j] & 0xff);//byte to int, trunc sign
        crc ^= ((crc & 0xff) >> 4);
        crc ^= (crc << 12) & 0xffff;
        crc ^= ((crc & 0xFF) << 5) & 0xffff;
    }
    crc &= 0xffff;
    return crc;

}
```

Comment: This is the CRC function I use in my code - provided the initial value is the same (0xFFFF) and the polynomial is the same (0x1021) they should give the exact same result.

Comment: The package I get is:
1 20 0 -30 -1 72 -31 -110 64 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 125 -7. 21 Bytes. The packages crc is then -1667. I had to change the order of the last to byte. When I use your algorithm crc delivers me 3377.

Comment: the data you should pass to my function is the buffer without the last two bytes. You can change my function to for (int i = 0; i < data.length-2; i++) so the last 2 bytes are not taken into account

Comment: This is how its currently looking like:
byte[] bx = new byte[packet.length - 2];
  for(int i = 0; i < bx.length; i++)
   bx[i] = packet[i];
  
  System.out.println(crc16(bx));

Comment: I saw i forgot to calculate the crc on the c side. But its still not working. Package content is: 1 20 0 -30 -1 72 -31 -110 64 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 51 -100. c crc is 13212 and java crc with your function 3377.

Comment: so, to be clear, the data is: {1 20 0 -30 -1 72 -31 -110 64 1 0 2 0 3 0 4 0 5 0 } and the checksum should be {51 -100} which, as short in the right byte order is 13212 ?

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i get with the c package. but calculating it with your algorithm, crc = 3377

Comment: byte[] fkk = {1,20,0,-30,-1,72,-31,-110,64,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0};
  debugPrintln("" + crc16(fkk));
  // = 3377

Comment: using the function and simply returning the value plus printing gives me 39987 instead of 13212. sure its working now?

Comment: Yes, you have just to swap the bytes.

Comment: 39987 is 9c33 in hex, 13212 is 339c

Comment: +1, much more efficient than other Java implementations with tables I have found.

Comment: @thedayofcondor hi, i have a doubt here. With respect to this link, the answer i get by implementing the code above falls in bad_crc category. http://srecord.sourceforge.net/crc16-ccitt.html#results. Can i get some helping hand understand it. CRC and bits is not my cup of tea ;)