# Transforming C-source CRC16CITT function to Java

Tags: java, c, bit-manipulation, crc, low-level

I'm trying to port the following method to Java. So far I've been unsuccessful. I've been researching stackoverflow and found couple of implementations of the problem but I can't get any of them to work.

[Convert C CRC16 to Java CRC16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209364/convert-c-crc16-to-java-crc16)

This seems really promising but I'm missing something here. Low level operations aren't my strength. This is part of communications protocol implementation with Java.

Below is example C-source code from the specification.

### Calculating CRC

The 16-bit CRC-CCITT Checksum is calculated from ID_H to the last databyte. See C-source example function as follows:

```
unsigned short crc;
crc = 0;
calc_crc( ID_H );
calc_crc( ID_L );
.
.
calc_crc( <last databyte>);
CRC_H = (unsigned char)(crc>>8);
CRC_L = (unsigned char)crc;
.
.
void calc_crc( unsigned char character )
{
unsigned short crc_tmp;
crc_tmp = (crc ^ character) & 0x0F;
crc = (crc >> 4) ^ (crc_tmp * 4225);
crc_tmp = (crc ^ (character >> 4)) & 0x0F;
crc = (crc >> 4) ^ (crc_tmp * 4225);
}
```

My current implementation:

```
public class CRC16CCITT {

    private static int crc = 0;

    private static void calc_crc(int character) {
        int crc_tmp;
        crc_tmp = ((crc ^ character) & 0x0F);
        crc = (crc >>> 4) ^ (crc_tmp * 4225);
        crc_tmp = ((crc ^ (character >>> 4)) & 0x0F);
        crc = (crc >>> 4) ^ (crc_tmp * 4225);
    }

    public static void update(byte b) {
        calc_crc(b);
    }

    public static void reset() {
        crc = 0;
    }

    public static int highByte() {
        return (( crc >> 8) & 0xFF);

    }

    public static int lowByte() {
        return crc & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int value() {
        return crc;
    }

    public static void main(string[] args) {

    // Refactoring test cases atm

    }
}
```

This works for some examples but I think it's failing when I use large numbers which surpass the signed byte interval. The server is C-made so this might be considerable factor. Help me out please.

Comment: Hey bitwise gurus, help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working like a charm. Just used integer type in each variable. I presume it uses a lot more of memory but It will do for now. Imitating Sun's class design.

```
/*
 * Class for calculating CRC16CITT. 
 */
public class CRC16CCITT {

    private static int crc = 0;

    public static void calc_crc(int character) {
        int crc_tmp;
        crc_tmp = ((crc ^ character) & 0x0F);
        crc = (crc >>> 4) ^ (crc_tmp * 4225);
        crc_tmp = ((crc ^ (character >>> 4)) & 0x0F);
        crc = (crc >>> 4) ^ (crc_tmp * 4225);
    }

    public static void update(byte b) {
        calc_crc(b);
    }

    public static void reset() {
        crc = 0;
    }

    public static int highByte() {
        return (( crc >> 8) & 0xFF);

    }

    public static int lowByte() {
        return crc & 0xFF;
    }

     public static int value() {
        return crc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need unsigned variables from C in Java, you have to use the larger java equivalent. `uint8_t` becomes `short`, `uint16_t` becomes `int`, and `uint32_t` becomes long.

You should also use `>>>` instead of `>>`. A short explanation why is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

As for CRC16 implementation -- I wrote this long ago, maybe it'll help:

```
public class CRC16 { 

    static int[] table = {
        0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241,
        0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500, 0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440,
        0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40,
        0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0, 0x0880, 0xC841,
        0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40,
        0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80, 0xDC41,
        0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641,
        0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
        0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240,
        0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441,
        0x3C00, 0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41,
        0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840,
        0x2800, 0xE8C1, 0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41,
        0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40,
        0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580, 0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640,
        0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041,
        0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141, 0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240,
        0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441,
        0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01, 0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41,
        0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840,
        0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0, 0x7A80, 0xBA41,
        0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40,
        0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681, 0x7640,
        0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041,
        0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
        0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440,
        0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40,
        0x5A00, 0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841,
        0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40,
        0x4E00, 0x8EC1, 0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41,
        0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641,
        0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380, 0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040,
    };

    public static int getCrc(byte[] bytes) {
        int crc = 0x0000;
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ b) & 0xff];
        }
        return crc;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks but couldn't get this. It returs a different value and I don't understand why.