# Java code for CRC 16 calculation

Tags: java, crc, crc16

Below is my hex string

```
String str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
```

and this is my CRC : **A228** which is appended to the above string.
I want output as **A228**

Polynomial used is 0xA001

Can  someone provide me the code to calculate the CRC16

Below is my java code

```
String str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

    byte arr[] = toByteArray(str);


        long polynomial = 0xA001;
        long CRC = 0xFFFF;

        for (byte b : arr)
        {
            CRC ^= b;
            for (int i = 8; i != 0; i--)
            {
                if ((CRC & 0x0001) != 0)
                {
                    CRC = (CRC >> 1) ^ polynomial;
                }
                else
                {
                    CRC >>= 1;
                }
            }
        }



        System.out.println(CRC);
```

}

I am getting output as -56289

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works. What have you tried? Have you tried to google `crc16 java`?

Comment: Yes of course !

Comment: What about this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13209435/921563

Comment: First of all your `toByteArray` implementation seems to be wrong, as your code outputs -56855 when using a correct Hex decoded `str`.

Comment: You certainly won’t see `A228` by just printing a long, since a long is only going to contain digits.  Perhaps you meant to print it in hex using `System.out.printf("%x%n", CRC);`?

Comment: I am getting output as  : ffffffffffff3637  @VGR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is mostly fine and will produce `0xa228` for that message (with the modification below), except you have to feed it the right data and then display the resulting CRC correctly.

To feed it the right data, you first need to convert that string of hexadecimal characters into half that many binary bytes. Give *that* to your CRC routine.

Second, display the result in hexadecimal, not decimal.

Third, `byte` is signed, so do `CRC ^= b & 0xff;` to avoid the sign extension.

Comment: I am converting the string into byte array.
Also I am printing it into hex and still I am getting output as : ffffffffffff3637

Comment: Read my answer more carefully. You need to convert the _hexadecimal_ into bytes. Your 1460 characters would become 730 bytes, not 1460 bytes.

Comment: Also I noticed that you need to fix the signed byte problem in Java.

Comment: You need to provide your `toByteArray` routine to know what's really going on here.